Singular data point not plotting
I am trying to plot the following code to get a plot that includes my data points, some with repeats so they have an error bar and others that are just points. Unfortunately my point at x = 150 does not show up on the resultant plot and I cannot figure out why. I am giving an example dataset.
xValues = {200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400};
yValues = {100, 123, 124, 250, 267, 
   274, 340, 352,322};

(*Additional points*)
additionalPoints = {{150, 145.59}, {250, 300}, {350, 
    380}, {450, 375}};

(*Combine x and y values*)
data = Transpose[{xValues, yValues}];

(*Compute average and standard deviation for each x value*)
averageData = Mean /@ GatherBy[data, First];
errors = 
  StandardDeviation /@ 
   GatherBy[data, First][[All, All, 2]]; (*Compute std dev*)

(*Extract x values,y average values,and standard deviations*)
xAvg = averageData[[All, 1]];
yAvg = averageData[[All, 2]];

(*Prepare data with Around for error bars*)
dataWithErrors = 
  Table[{xAvg[[i]], Around[yAvg[[i]], errors[[i]]]}, {i, 
    Length[xAvg]}];

(*Fit a linear model including all points*)
fit = LinearModelFit[Join[averageData, additionalPoints], x, x];
(*Error check to see if the code recognizes all the points*)
c = Join[averageData, additionalPoints]
(*Get equation and R^2 value*)
equation = fit["BestFit"];
rSquared = fit["RSquared"];

(*Format values without rounding*)
formatNumber[num_] := 
  NumberForm[N[num], {Infinity, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)];

(*Plotting*)
Show[ListPlot[dataWithErrors,(*Use dataWithErrors directly*)
  Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], RGBColor[0.6, 0.2, 0.8]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, All},(*Adjusted plot range*)Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Axis", 
     FontFamily -> "Arial", 14], 
    Style["Axis", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     14]},(*X and Y axis labels*)
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, 
    None},(*Display numbers on Y axis*)
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{Style["Title", 
      FontFamily -> "Arial", 14], "\n\n", "Linear Fit: y = ", 
     formatNumber[equation], "\n", "R^2 = ", 
     formatNumber[rSquared]}],(*Set font to Arial and add space*)
  Epilog -> {{RGBColor[0.8, 0.8, 1], Thick, Dashed, 
     Line[{{0, fit[Min[xValues]]}, {500, 
        fit[Max[xValues]]}}]} (*Extend the line of best fit within \
the data range*), {RGBColor[0.6, 0.2, 0.8], PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[additionalPoints]} (*Additional points in purple*)}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"} (*Set base style for the entire plot*)]]


MMA 14.0  The point[{150,145}] is displayed.

Can you show me? I just updated and it still isn't showing for me

In "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)", I get this, which shows the point. You might need to add PlotRange -> All or something, depending on your version.

Here is the requested picture:

